# Float button position

Tags: forms, buttons, registration, ajax

I have a register form where the user can select the type of registration, for example, 'Solo Artist' and 'Band', when the user select one of them the register form is loaded ('Register' button is at bottom of the form) via ajax and centered in the page, if the user want to change his registration type I need to reload the page, but is not very convenient so I thought in a 'Refresh/Back' float button in the right side of the form to remove the current form and load the original select type registration form without load the page, is just a show and hide actions.

My question is: How should it look? Should say 'Back' or 'Refresh'? What about an icon? and the most importante Where should I put it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Definitely "Back" or "Previous" and not "Refresh" - the last usually means something like "redraw the current page".  But why can't you just repeat the option field for selecting the registration type at the top of the registration page?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @montogeek!  At the moment, your question's rather ambiguous.  Can you add an image of what you have so far?  Who are your users?  What are your main objective and concerns?

Answer (score 1):

If the user has to actually *start over* just to change the **Registration Type**, you could simply use a **Start Over** button next to the **Register** button.

However, if you *don't* have to start over and since you said you are using ajax, you should be able to asynchronously update both the server and the client.  You could then just have ajax loaders over the areas that are updating.

That said, it might make more since to leave **Registration Type** visible so that it could be changed at any point.  When the selection is changed and it differs from the previous selection, you would do like I said above and asynchronously update everything that needs updating.